# In SlimDX and DX9 what is the suffix "Ex" that is on the end of some classes mean?

Tags: graphics, direct3d, slimdx

I have noticed that in the SlimDX.Direct3D9 namespace there is a lot of classes and methods with two different versions. One version has an Ex suffix. I think this is true of the DX9 API as well.

For example:

SlimDX.Direct3D9.Device

SlimDX.Direct3D9.DeviceEx

SlimDX.Direct3D9.DisplayMode

SlimDX.Direct3D9.DisplayModeEx

Comment: So should I be using the Ex version when available?

Comment: Do you need it? Is the non-Ex version marked obsolete?

Comment: Opps I edited out his comment by mistake can some one reverse that?

Comment: I deleted it :) You can't edit comments of others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Ex**-tended is how I've always read it in my head (although it could be wrong).

C does not have overloading so if the API is updated to account for extra stuff not originally accounted for, such as a new option field, enter in `FooEx`. (The same reasoning applies to new types, even though the overloading is not applicable.)

While other languages *do* have overloads, wrappers may keep the `Ex` convention to better mirror the underlying source API, including using the "annotation" on types.

This naming convention is consistently used across large portions of Win-C/Microsoft API, but *could* have been `Foo2`, had that been the convention.

Answer (score 1):

DirectX9Ex is mostly an improvement for DirectX9, adding new features for Windows Vista and later versions only (the most notable being the ability to share resources).

There's a few incompatibilities between each, for example when creating resources you have to be careful of which pool you choose (Pool.Managed with work with Device but you need Pool.Default with DeviceEx )

If you need to share textures across processes, DeviceEx is you only option, otherwise standard Device will do just fine.